# Multiple string matching possibilities condition in R

Tags: r

I have a variable called Country and I would like to create a subset where Country equals Australia and Greece. In this case, I tried to do like this and failed.

```
CUTdata <- subset(NEWdata, Country == c('Australia','Greece'))
```

This does not work. What is another way to achieve this kind of logic?

Comment: Use `%in%`. `subset(NEWdata, Country %in% c('Australia', 'Greece'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grep. Just like in Unix. You can also ignore case and do partial matches.

```
CUTdata <- grep( 'Australia|Greece' , NEWdata, value = T, ignore.case = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

.... Or use the `sqldf` package :)

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from Newdata where Country in ('Australia' ,'Greece')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', `set` the key column as 'Country', and subset the row in the dataset where the 'Country' is 'Australia' or 'Greece'.

```
setDT(NEWdata, key='Country')[c('Australia', 'Greece')]
#     Country       value
#1: Australia  0.59826911
#2: Australia -0.08554095
#3: Australia  0.11953107
#4: Australia -0.94382724
#5:    Greece -1.31690812
#6:    Greece -0.33498679
#7:    Greece  0.51633570
#8:    Greece -0.60515695
#9:    Greece -0.64859151
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
NEWdata <- data.frame(Country = sample(c("Australia", 
  "Greece", "USA", "UK"), 20, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(20))
```